# How to apply translation, rotation and scaling a non square matrix in GLM?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I tried translating a `glm::mat3x2` using the `glm::translate(matrix, vector)` from `glm/gtx/transform.hpp` but I got an error:

```sh
no matching function for call to 'translate(glm::mat3x2, glm::vec2)'
```

Comment: Of course it is an error, what does it even mean to *translate a 3x2 matrix*? What does the matrix contain?

Comment: @Quimby shouldn't I be able to do 2D transformation? JOML (the java equivalent of GLM) allows 2D transformation using 3x2 matrix

Comment: But 2D homogeneous coordinates use 3x3 matrices for transformations, not 3x2. What does the 3x2 matrix store? Anyway GLM supports this with `GLM_GTX_matrix_transform_2d` extension, but again, it uses 3x3 matrices.

Comment: In order to do a translation by matrix multiplication (in contrast to adding a matrix) the are preconditions for the matrx to translate. Use the method applied in opengl. I.e. use a higher order matrix, which has a 1.0 in strategic locations.

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]